# VS2012C++: Hundreds of errors when compiling glee.h file

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, header-files, cinder

I am using Windows7 64bit with VS2012. When including "gl/gl.h", I get more than 100 errors when the compiler tries to compile glee.h. I have included windows.h in glee.h before including gl.h like the others said to do but I am still getting errors. If you need any other information I will be glad to post it on here.

The Errors:
http://usandfriends.x10.mx/OTHER/100s-of-errors-when-trying-to-compile-glee_h-vs2012-c__.html

My .cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include "gl/gl.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The VS2012 version of gl/gl.h does *not* include a file named glee.h.  Sounds like you've been overwriting files.  Bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify any of the system headers (like glee.h or windows.h).

This .cpp file compiles fine for me:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include "GLee.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is all you need. There is no need to include gl.h when including glee.h. Actually you don't have to include Windows.h as well because its already included by glee.h, but that doesn't matter.